# Android - Getting User Input As An Integer

Tags: android, string, android-emulator, integer, int

I'm a new Android developer. As a starting project, I'm trying to create a basic addition calculator. I have an `EditText` which is supposed to take the input (input is a string) and convert it to `int1` when `Button1` is pressed. When `Button2` is pressed, it is supposed to take the input, convert it to `int2`, add `int1` and `int2` together and store the result in the int `ans`, and set the text of the `EditText` to ans. However, when I try to use `Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString())` I get an error and the app force closes. Could anyone provide me with the code to properly convert these Strings to integers? Thank you.

```
static int fn = 0;
static int sn = 0;
static int ans = 0;
static int pro = 0;
//"+" Button Clicked//
if(pro == 0){
    fn = Integer.parseInt(entry.getText().toString());
    entry.setText("");
    pro++;
}else{
    //MessageBox Crap//

//"=" Button Clicked//
    sn = Integer.parseInt(entry.getText().toString());
    ans = fn + sn;
    entry.setText(ans);
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with the code from your own attempt at the problem?

Comment: Also post the specific log message. Since it seems like you're on the right track, I would bet there's a null pointer exception.

Comment: The String to int conversion seems to be OK.
What error did you get? Can you post the logcat output?

Comment: * Question Edited. There was no error, It just said app stopped working in the emulator. It can get the string, but the error appears when the conversion takes place. I used a breakpoint and stepped through.

Comment: Its also worth noting that I tried to set a String to entry.getText().toString() and then do Integer.ParseInt(//String variable//)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't ans be converted to a string before you set the contents of the EditText?

Comment: The error happened before that, but thank you, that will help later.

Comment: Yep. Cast it like entry.setText(Integer.toString(yournumber));

Comment: Could calling toString() on entry.getText() be doing anything?

Comment: I tried that but no dice. If your asking if toString() serves any functionality, I think it simply returns a String value. entry.getText() is a String value, but it can't be assigned to a variable, only printed.

Comment: entry.getText() returns CharSequence, so you with entry.getText().toString() you are making it string, and then you parse it integer (what you did in your code) then you do your operations and when it comes to entry.setText() you do entry.setText(Integer.toString(yournumber)). NOTE: Check if the getText() returns null or empty string or there is no numbers in the input.

Comment: Thank you, but when I started getting the error, I rewrote the code leaving out the operator method(= button listener). The issue was with the parsing, not the setText(). I did Toast.message to print getText(), it returned the String of what was in the EditText. it was not null, only empty when nothing was entered in the Edittext.

Comment: Why dont you set the EditText takes only numeric values with placing tag in xml android:inputType="number" ? That would be much more convenient...IMHO

Comment: This would accept the input as an Integer? Wouldn't this only prevent me from entering letters, and the input would still be a String?

Comment: Yep, but for the sake of being friendly UI :D You can do it, both ways are not expensive...

Comment: Ok but I still have the issue of parsing the integer. This is more of a lead-in project, I will need the parsing later on.